# SQL query works but ActiveRecord syntax returns errors or an empty relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

`CreditCard` `belongs_to` `User`. `Subscription` also `belongs_to` `User`. A `User` `has_one` `Subscription` and `has_many` `CreditCard`s.

I need to query `CreditCard`s that belong to a User whose `Subscription.status` is `"authorized"`.

This is the query that is working for me:

```
select * from credit_cards
join users on users.id = credit_cards.user_id
join subscriptions on users.id = subscriptions.user_id
where subscriptions.status = 'authorized'
```

But when I do `CreditCard.joins(:user).joins(:subscription)` even without the where clause, I get an empty relation:

```
#<CreditCard::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x2ace5a5be2f0>
```

If I append .emtpy to the query result, I get:

> Can't join 'CreditCard' to association named 'subscriptions'; perhaps you misspelled it?

Why is it not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your associations are chained through one to another, you should do the following:

```
CreditCard.joins(user: :subscription)
          .where(subscriptions: { status: :authorized })
```

Comment: Thank you. A small typo in there `CreditCard.joins(user: :subscription).where(subscriptions: { status:  "authorized" })`

Comment: @pinkfloyd90: `:authorized` should work as well, there was an extra space at first causing the mistake, but i ve already removed it

Answer (score 2):

`CreditCard.joins(user: :subscription)`

For more info about `joins`, see part *12.1.3 Joining Multiple Associations*  in https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/active_record_querying.html#joins

Comment: Thank you. It does work, but I can't manage to filter correctly using the `where` clause. `CreditCard.joins(user: :subscription).where(status: "authorized")` returns an empty collection. Whereas `CreditCard.joins(user: :subscription).where("subscription.status" == "WHATEVER")` returns all credit cards.